# Destroy an object in model file if its missing a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can i destroy this object if its category_attributes(:title) is empty?

```
def categories_attributes=(categories_attributes)
    categories_attributes.values.each do |category_attribute|
      category = Category.find_or_create_by(category_attribute)
      categories << category
    end
  end
```

Comment: Basically how can i validate that :title is not empty in this hash passed in categories_attributes before i destroy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def categories_attributes=(categories_attributes)
  categories_attributes.values.each do |category_attribute|
    category = Category.find_or_create_by(category_attribute)
    if category.title?
      categories << category
    elsif category.persisted?
      category.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: got the following error below `undefined method `presisted?' for #<Category id: nil, title: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

Comment: Fixed the typo, try now.

Comment: I never seen the presisted? before

Comment: In Rails `persisted?` and `new_record?` are twins. Doc can be found here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/persisted%3F

Comment: I would surround the call or the method block within a transaction. Otherwise, rails commits for every `has_many` append.